# ASP.NET MVC 2 - How do I pass a querystring back on response?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to pass a querystring back on response - so that via means of jQuery I can do something with it.

something like this:
return RedirectToAction("LogOn", "Account", new { id = "?action=update" });

URL needs to end up like: ../Account/LogOn/?action=update

but the above code produces this instead: ../Account/LogOn/%3faction%3dupdate

I don't want the encoding...

Help?

Comment: Any particular reason you want to use a query string rather than putting the action right into the path, e.g. `/Account/LogOn/update`?  You could also define a route that is Account/LogOn/{action} or similar or maybe use an Area = Account, controller = LogOn, Action= update ...

Comment: @Hightechrider - the reason is because client-side code is going to want to retrieve some parameters

Comment: Most people use hidden fields, javascript constants, cookies, ... to pass parameters to their javascript, not query string parameters that a user can modify all too easily.

Answer (score 3):

I think, in this case, you should use

```
return RedirectToAction("About", "Home", new { sendto = "update" });
```

You can't use the keyword "action" because it will be consumed by mvc, so I've replaced it with "sendto" instead.

Comment: Regarding the action keyword, maybe @action = "update" would work? @ seems to be used to escape keywords, like @class.

Comment: In this case it's not the same thing action is a special keyword used by MVC to handle routing information whereas class is a special keyword used by c# - which is why the need to escape it.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, name the parameter with the @ sign, as Pawel writes. 
So

```
public ActionResult YourAction(string @action)  will work
public ActionResult YourAction(string action)  will fail
```